# BSOD after EAC loads when launching Rust

Tags: rust

Whenever I launch *Rust*, it seems to load fine.
But then after, *EasyCheatEngine* loads and my computer blue screens with "Page fault in nonpaged area" and the EasyAntiCheat.sys as the failed file (which apparently doesn't exist on my computer and all attempts to get it on my computer were unsuccessful).

After tons of troubleshooting, I have been unsuccessful with finding a solution.
I also play *7 days to die* which uses *EAC*, but it works well.
If relevant, I also have access to the dxdiag.txt file.